# Laravel Validation : Validate only if fields are present

Tags: validation, laravel-5

So I have fields that are to be hidden if it met certain conditions. And now I'm having problem in my validation. Here's what I have:

**blade.php**

```
<div class="{{ $room['show_checkin_out'] ? '' : 'hide-fields' }}">
    <div class="form-group check-in-dtls">
        <label for="before_checkin">@lang('before_checkin')</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="before_checkin" name="before_checkin" placeholder="@lang('before_checkin')" value="{{ old('before_checkin', '') }}">
        @if ($errors->has('before_checkin'))
            <div class="form-group">
                <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('before_checkin') }}</p>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

**validation file**

```
'before_checkin' => ['sometimes', 'required', 'max:255'],
```

**css**

```
.hide-fields{
    display: none;
}
```

I would like the fields to be required only if it is shown and my validation is not working well. For this one, what is the best approach to do?

Comment: you can do  the trick with jquery by removing `name` attribute from input filed if `hide-fields`  class is exist

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest 3 ways.

1. Just don't add this validation rule at all if `$room['show_checkin_out']` is falsy.

Kind of:

```
$rules = [...];
if ($room['show_checkin_out']) {
    $rules['before_checkin'] = ['sometimes', 'required', 'max:255'];
}
```

2. Use "Required With" rule (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-with).
   Simply pass `show_checkin_out` as a hidden parameter when necessary and make `before_checkin` required only when `show_checkin_out` is present.

Add into your form:

```
@if($room['show_checkin_out'])
    <input type="hidden" name="show_checkin_out" value="1"/>
@endif
```

Modify the validation rule this way:

```
'before_checkin' => ['required_with:show_checkin_out', 'sometimes', 'max:255'],
```

3. Probably the best one. Since you already have `sometimes` rule then basically don't output the `before_checkin` field when `show_checkin_out` is falsy:

```
@if($room['show_checkin_out'])
    <div class="form-group check-in-dtls">
        <label for="before_checkin">@lang('before_checkin')</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="before_checkin" name="before_checkin" placeholder="@lang('before_checkin')" value="{{ old('before_checkin', '') }}">
        @if ($errors->has('before_checkin'))
            <div class="form-group">
                <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('before_checkin') }}</p>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `display:none` property you can do this.

```
@if(isset($room['show_checkin_out']))
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group check-in-dtls">
    <label for="before_checkin">@lang('before_checkin')</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="before_checkin" name="before_checkin" placeholder="@lang('before_checkin')" value="{{ old('before_checkin', '') }}">
     @if ($errors->has('before_checkin'))
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('before_checkin') }}</p>
         </div>
     @endif
   </div>
 </div>
@endif
```

If it's set `$room['show_checkin_out']` it will create that part and will validate or else it will not create that section and your validation will work as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

So finally, I have done this way to do the validation working.

**blade**

```
.... name="{{ $room['show_checkin_out']==1 ? 'before_checkin' : '' }}"
```

**validation**

```
$ret = [
       // other validation
       ];

if (\Request::has('before_checkin')) {
    $ret['before_checkin'] = ['required', 'sometimes', 'max:255'];
}
```

It's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
'before_checkin' => ['required_if:show_checkin_out,true']
```

You can also check Laravel documentation

```
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if
```